# Glitchy transition while pushing and popping using UINavigationController

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am using UINavController to push and pop between viewcontrollers. However when I push and pop the animation is not smooth. The navbar backbutton transition happens first and then the view and its title. This lapse in timing makes it look as if a block appears between two views. I am not doing anything fancy and I commented out code from viewwillappear and viewdidappear, but still the problem occurs.

Has anyone seen such a problem or have a suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem is with an image view I added to the view to hold the background image. It does not move in sync with the view.

Comment: to elaborate on the problem, I have an uiimageview as subview to the main view of the controller, but the uiimageview did not have flexible width/height set through IB. Hence it was visible even before the view could slide in.